# Why user in the same group is denied permission in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, permissions, hdfs

I want to set Access Control on my  Hadoop distributed file system. So I have set `dfs.permissions=true`. But I'm confused why a user in the same group can't write to the directory with permissions: 775.

```
[abc@hadoop03 root]$ hadoop fs -ls /zqq
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   3 hbase zq       1021 2015-11-19 11:29 /zqq/group

[abc@hadoop03 root]$ hadoop fs -put /etc/passwd /zqq
put: Permission denied: user=abc, access=WRITE, inode="/zqq":zq:zq:drwxrwxr-x

[abc@hadoop03 root]$ id
uid=1012(abc) gid=1009(zq) groups=1009(zq)
```

Comment: oh! ,it's necessary to define OS user at all nodes in cluster?